# Как задать один внешний ключ

Tags: c#

Как из двух внешних ключей сделать один?

Имееются 2 таблицы Cat и Dog. Сущности:

```
public abstract class AnimalEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public AnimalType Type { get; set; }

    public AnimalBreed Breed { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Feeding> Feedings { get; set; } 
}

public class Cat : AnimalEntity
{
    public decimal Weight { get; set; }
}

public class Dog : AnimalEntity
{
    public decimal TailLength { get; set; }
}
```

Также есть таблица с кормлением этих животных.

```
public class Feeding
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public Food Food { get; set; }

    public int Count { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CatId")]
    public Cat Cat { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DogId")]
    public Dog Dog { get; set; }

}
```

Она имеет два внешних ключа. Как сделать так чтобы в таблице находился только один столбец содержащий эти внешние ключи?

Констекст

```
    public DbSet<AnimalBreed> AnimalBreeds { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Food> Foods { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Cat> Cats { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Feeding> Feedings { get; set; }

    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<AnimalBreed>().Property(e => e.Type)
            .HasConversion(
            x => x.ToString(),
            v => (AnimalType)Enum.Parse(typeof(AnimalType), v));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Cat>().Property(e => e.Type)
            .HasConversion(
            x => x.ToString(),
            v => (AnimalType)Enum.Parse(typeof(AnimalType), v));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Dog>().Property(e => e.Type)
            .HasConversion(
            x => x.ToString(),
            v => (AnimalType)Enum.Parse(typeof(AnimalType), v));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Food>().Property(e => e.Type)
            .HasConversion(
            x => x.ToString(),
            v => (AnimalType)Enum.Parse(typeof(AnimalType), v));

    }
```

Comment: `один столбец содержащий эти внешние ключи` вы это руками в БД вообще сможете сделать? Какой смысл в таком ключе?

Answer (score 0):

Должно работать, но у этого есть ограничения

```
public class Animal
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AnimalTypeId")]
    public AnimalType AnimalType { get; set; }
    public Guid AnimalTypeId { get; set; }
}

public class AnimalType
{
    [ForeignKey("Animal")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Animal Animal { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FeedingId")]
    public Feeding Feeding { get; set; }
    public Guid FeedingId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Feeding
{
    [ForeignKey("AnimalType")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public AnimalType AnimalType { get; set; }
}
```